# <Div> works like Radio Button

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, toggle

How can make it select/deselect only one element within ng-repeat?
So far I have this code, but in this way I can select any element, not just one:

```
<div data-ng-repeat="images in list">
    <div data-ng-class="isImageSelected ? 'selected' : ''" data-ng-click="isImageSelected = !isImageSelected">
        something
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: provide code for isImageSelected please

Comment: isImageSelected just a variable, true or false

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check this:   [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Upal_Roy/U3pVM/19314/)

```
<ul>
  <li data-ng-repeat="image in images">
    <div data-ng-class="{'selected':  isSelected == $index}" data-ng-click="updateSelected($index)">a</div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: My code is working in this way (toggle), the only thing is missing, that when  I click one of the element the other is deselecting

Comment: Sorry, no, it doesn't work. The only thing that is missing, is that when I click the now to be selected element, I require the already selected element to be deselected.

Comment: The methodology is now, like checkbox (you can select all, if you want), but I need radio

Comment: I think I need to do something with $index

Comment: This is the same version like mine. When you select the first one, makes it green. Perfect. When you select the second or third one, makes it green. Almost good. The first selected should go deselected state.

Comment: Now is the other part. I need the mixture of the two version. Almost good. If you make it deselect-able, that would be great.
So first one is checked, ok. But I need to uncheck as well.

Comment: but when you select one <div> other <div>'s are automatically unselecteda as like radio button. Now what do you want????

Comment: Thank you for your help so far. Would it be possible to be able to unselect all items; at the moment one item must be checked on but my need will be to allow the user the un-check any selections leaving all items in the list unchecked; is this more of a checkbox / radio button mixture ?

Comment: Absolutely perfect! Sorry about the trouble and unclear sentences. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
<div data-ng-repeat="images in list">
<div data-ng-class="{'col-sm-12' : isImageSelected, 'col-sm-9' : !isImageSelected}" data-ng-click="isImageSelected = !isImageSelected">
    something
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need keys to add class to specific element in the ng-repeat, so basically the  snippet will look like this:

```
<div data-ng-repeat="( key,image ) in list">
    <div data-ng-class="activeImage === key ? 'selected' : ''" data-ng-click="activeImage = key">
        something
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have replied this simple code with buttons and numbers and it is working for me:

```
<div ng-repeat="(key, number) in myCtrl.numbers">
    <button class="btn " ng-class="isImageSelected ? 'btn-success' : ''" ng-init="isImageSelected = false" ng-click="isImageSelected = !isImageSelected">
        {{number}}
    </button>
</div>
```

And in my controller I have `vm.numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`

Here ng-init is creating different variables in scope for each iteration of ng-repeat, and does not call the same variable as your code was doing. You should not abuse of ng-init like the docs says https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit